# Facebook Marketing API Ad wise Share count

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

I am using facebook marketing API and I try to use action_type,action_reaction. It gives me a reaction(like,wow,sad,...) and Number of comments data but Its not returning share count data. 
I am looking to share count.

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/act_Xyz/insights?access_token=Xyz&level=ad&fields=account_name,campaign_name,adset_name,ad_name,spend,clicks,cpc,actions&default_summary=false&time_range=%7B%22since%22:%222019-02-03%22,%22until%22:%222019-02-03%22%7D

```
"actions": [
        {
           "action_type": "landing_page_view",
           "value": "95"
        },
        {
           "action_type": "comment",
           "value": "1"
        },
        {
           "action_type": "link_click",
           "value": "273"
        },
        {
           "action_type": "post_reaction",
           "value": "3"
        },
        {
           "action_type": "post_engagement",
           "value": "277"
        },
        {
           "action_type": "page_engagement",
           "value": "277"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the share count alone is only available on post level:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/post

It will be an object with the number of shares in `shares.count`.

Comment: Ok I know it but I am looking of advertisements data